# Azure AutoScaleの参照VHDファイルの差し替えをPowershellで行いたい

Tags: azure, powershell

AzureのAutoScaleにおいて、元となるVMSSのOSディスクのURI変更をPowershellで行いたいと考えています。
コマンド自体はUpdate-azurermvmssで実行できたのですが、DefaultでVMの数を指定している場合、少なくともその台数分は最初に作られて消える事が無い為、AutoScaleして作られたVMとイメージに違いが出てしまいます。
全てのVMSSに新しいカスタムイメージを適用する事はできないのでしょうか？

作成されるVMの最小値とDefault値を一旦0にして全てのVMを消した後、元の値に戻す事で全てのVMにイメージの適用はできるのですが、これを行うとAutoScaleしている間VMが全て消える時間が発生してしまい、サービスダウンしてしまうのでできれば別の方法を考えたいと思っています。

Comment: 参考までに再現できそうなMin環境の情報を書いてもらえるとうれしいです。（特にベースにしているVMイメージや手順的なもの）

Comment: すみませんコメント頂いているのに気付きませんでした。。。ベースはCentOS6.7です。マーケットプレイスから購入したものを特に設定を弄らずにキャプチャしてカスタムイメージを作って使用しました。手順も単純で、Get-AzureRmVmssコマンドで情報を取得して参照先のカスタムイメージのURLを変更した後Update-AzureRmVmssコマンドで反映、インスタンスIDを指定してUpdate-AzureRmVmssVmコマンドでアップデートをしたらタイムアウトしました。

Answer (score 1):

Update-AzureRmVmssInstance を使ってインスタンスIDで指定したものをUpdateできると思いますがどうでしょう。

参考: [How to upgrade an Azure VM Scale Set without shutting it down](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/05/17/how-to-upgrade-an-azure-vm-scale-set-without-shutting-it-down/)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。カスタムイメージを差し替えた後Update-azurermvmssInstanceを使用して、イメージが更新されている事が確認できました。

Comment: すみません、また詰まってて質問させてください。。。

色々検証していると、Update文を流してVMを更新すると、一部のVMがUpdatingのステータスで止まってしまい、コマンドが帰ってこなくなります。
現状、VMSSのデフォルトVM数を2台に設定していますが、一台はコマンドが成功し、もう一台がコマンドが止まってしまいます。

現状カスタムイメージの差し替えは、Get-AzureRmVmssで取得した情報のURIを更新してUpdate-AzurermVmssを実行した後、インスタンス毎に更新をかけています。
手順が何か間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: 手順はあってると思うんですけどね、、OperationIDなどがあればサポートに状況を問い合わせることも可能だと思います。（※1台成功しているのであれば古いのを削除して増やすとかのほうが良いのかも…）

Comment: OperationIDはNULLでした。削除も考えましたが、ダウンタイムが発生する事からできれば取りたくないんですよね。。。一台も成功しないパターンも有りましたし。

Comment: 一台も成功しないのは困りますね… ちなみにupgradePolicyはManualでしょうか？ Update-AzureRmVmssInstanceはマニュアル用な気がします。

Comment: 今確認したらマニュアルでした。諦めて別の方法が無いか模索してみます・・・

Answer (score -1):

コメントが追加できなかったので、別回答で失礼します。
私も何度かカスタムイメージのアップグレードを試しましたが、そのような挙動になったことはないですね。。。
一度サポートのほうに問い合わせをすることをお勧めします。
ちなみにコマンドが止まってしまうとは具体的にどのような挙動でしょうか？